# I cannot display an image using shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

My code is following:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Installation"),
      p("Shiny is available on CRAN, so you can install it on the usual way from your R console:"),
      div("install packages('shiny')", style="color:red"),
      img(src="C:/Users/asus/Desktop/App-1/rstudio.png", height=70, width=200)
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

#define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried to install all necessary packages and still it seems that the image is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: If shiny application doesn't display image, create a folder named "www" in the working directory and upload image there.**

Use this to display image, you can also change the style for yourself:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Installation"),
      p("Shiny is available on CRAN, so you can install it on the usual way from your R console:"),
      div("install packages('shiny')", style="color:red"),
      img(src="https://www.skoda-dobron.pl/assets/AKOL/1470/1b671b3ff2/4960013_z2.jpg",height=300,width=300,style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 10px;")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)
```

Second option with `tabPanel` and `htmlOutput`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Installation"),
      p("Shiny is available on CRAN, so you can install it on the usual way from your R console:"),
      div("install packages('shiny')", style="color:red"),
      tabPanel("name",htmlOutput("introduction"))
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$introduction <- renderText({
    paste("<img src=\"https://www.skoda-dobron.pl/assets/AKOL/1470/1b671b3ff2/4960013_z2.jpg
            \" width=\"90%\" height=\"90%\">")
  })
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: But what is the logic behind it? Why does not work my code but yours does?

Comment: it is possible that you have set the working directory incorrectly or entered the file extension incorrectly

Comment: Try creating a "www" folder in your working directory and upload the image there. More info here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/image-not-showing-r-shiny-displayed-as-broken/102750/4